# I.N Herstein Page 32 Example 2.2.8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> > #Example 2.2.8 Let $G$ be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, not both $0$. (We can state this more succinctly by saying that $a^2+b^2\neq0$.) Using the same operation as in the preceding two examples, we can easily show that G becomes a group. In fact, G is an infinite, abelian group.
>
> Does the multiplication in $G$ remind you of anything? Write $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ as $aI+bJ$ where $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and compute the product in these terms. Perhaps that will ring a bell with you.

What's the author talking about?

Comment: Did you do what the author proposes in the second parraph? Did you notice $\;J^2=-I\;$?

Comment: I hope that nobody will spoil the nice answer! Obviously, Herstein wants you to think about it.

Comment: @K.Dutta Once again: did you do what the author PROPOSES?

Comment: @Timbuc author says compute the product in these terms ..What did he mean by "compute the product "

Comment: @K.Dutta Apparenly he wants you to try, instead of product of two matrices just like that, to do the product $\;(aI+bJ)(\alpha I+\beta J)\;$ in this form

Comment: Compute $(a I + b J) (c I + d J)$, and write it in the form $x I + y J$. At this stage, according to Herstein, bells should start ringing.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti i get $(ac-bd)I + (ad+bc)J $

Comment: @Timbuc i get $(ac-bd)I + (ad+bc)J $

Comment: @K.Dutta Nice! Even I, so far away, can hear the rings...ring, ring!

Comment: I'd like to give a hint here, but it's a bit complex for a comment.

Comment: @K.Dutta Take a peek at the definition of operations in your most well known fields

Comment: @K.Dutta Nop, I do not quit. Further hint: what fields do **you** know? How are they defined, and how are the operations in them defined?

Comment: @Timbuc I donot know what are we trying to get at basically ?i know about basic field R ,C ..

Comment: @K.Dutta Good...so? Do you have your notes on these fields, or even just google them...?

Comment: @Timbuc i have Linear Algebra By Hoffman . I read about fields in it yesterday ..

Comment: Get another book or go to the net,as H-K don't deal with fields' definition in almost any depth.

Comment: @Timbuc, K.Dutta. I very much approve with this way of teaching/hinting. Unfortunately the number of comments generates a system flag. Here's a suggestion. When you are done one of you could post an answer (if K.Dutta it should include thanks to Timbuc). Possibly both of you could do that! And then remove the comments that have outlived their usefulness. In the end @-ping me to remove this :-) That way everybody will be happy!

Comment: @K.Dutta I have never understood that "rule" of this site to restrict the number of comments: either there's some unknown, obscure *good* reason for that, or else it is something esoteric, occult, religious or very, very secret about it...Anyway, you can open a chat room for this question and we can ask Kyrki to send all the comments there before they get sent to hel...I mean, before they get deleted. I don't intend to answer the question as I believe this is something so basic that *anyone* aspiring to study seriously linear algebra should know/deduce by himself.

Comment: Don't feel too much pressure. I am myself known for violating the recommendation that the length of comment exchanges should be limited to 20. This is something that comes with the diamond :-)